# How is handle 'Optimistic Locking' in API Gateway + DynamoDB combo

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

I recently started working on API Gateway with DynamoDB. Its going really cool, as it is that easy to expose a database operation as a service using API Gateway.

I am currently looking at Data integrity side of things, as we are going to use this combo for a sensitive use case. How can I improve data integrity when I use API Gateway + DynamoDB.

This documentation from AWS explains 'Optimistic locking' from JAVA & .Net SDK perspective - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.OptimisticLocking.html

But when I use dynamodb through API gateway, how can I enable 'Optimistic locking' ? As I won't be using Java / .Net SDKs. I don't see any related documentation.

Or I don't have to worry about Data integrity side of things, if I use API Gateway in front of DynamoDB. Just thinking this way, because even the update / getItem operation doesn't talk about it :)

Any thoughts ?

Cheers

Comment: Data integrity will still be a problem you will need to solve. You will have to implement optimistic locking on the client side.

Comment: @Shibashis Thanks, you mean to say I will have to build a custom optimistic locking mechanism myself ? like introduce a custom field for versions and manually check them in my code ? Because my client is just going to invoke a REST endpoint for read and write.

Comment: yes. You will have use client side logic with conditional writes feature of dynamo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building optimistic locking is possible with the help of  Conditional Writes no matter which language you are using to access DynamoDB.

More information about Conditional Writes: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.SpecifyingConditions.html